# mixed sorting in extjs grid

Tags: sorting, extjs, types, grid

I want to sort a column based on text and numbers.

values i have are sorted like this:

```
- List:010
 - List:100
 - List:134
 - List:2
 - List:204
```

but what i need is

```
- List:2
 - List:010
 - List:100
 - List:134
 - List:204
```

the column type i am using is string. i tried to use sortType but that was not working.

```
{
            name: 'listItems',
            type: 'string',
            mapping: 'listItems'
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ExtJS 4.x, you can take advantage of the SortTypes class.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.data.SortTypes, {
    asPerson: function(person){
        // expects an object with a first and last name property
        return person.lastName.toUpperCase() + person.firstName.toLowerCase();
    }    
});

Ext.define('Employee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'person',
        sortType: 'asPerson'
    }]
});
```

More information [on the SortTypes doc page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes).